# Is it safe to keep a reference of a state in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I get the general idea that the `StatefulWidget` my get rebuild very often, and even get assigned to a different `State` if not using key in some cases. However the `State` of that `widget` always exists in memory. I need to change some data of the `State` when it's not shown. Is it safe to keep the reference of that `State` instance for example in a singleton and change its data?

Specifically, I have a `StatefulWidget`(call it homapage) with `PageView`. Its `State` keeps the reference of the `PageController`. I want to change the `controller.page` when the screen is showing other tabs rather than homepage.  I did this via keeping a reference of the `State` in a singleton. In order to do it, I need to make the `State` class public by deleting the `_` in front of the `State` class name. If feels unsafe and against the Flutter design philosophy to me.

Comment: Look at Provider state management

Answer (score 0):

The state will be destroyed when a widget that uses that state is no longer in the widget tree. We recommend that you use GlobalKey and don't use a singleton as a reference to the State. Using InheritedWidget is also a good option.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to Flutter, not familiar with GlobalKey or InheritedWidget. I'll look into them. I'm assuming that I can get the instance of the State via GolabKey's `currentContext` right? All I need to do is save the reference of the key in the singleton manager right?

Comment: you can get the instance using currentState

Comment: Thank you. But if we think it this way: No matter using my old way or the global key, I need to keep the reference of the State or the GlobalKey in my singleton manager in `initState()`. When I need to use the State, I get it via singleton. When the State is destroyed and rebuilt, the process goes over again so the reference in my plan or the GlobalKey's currentState points to the new instance of the `State`. It seems to me that essentially these plans are the same, and using a direct reference is much simpler and cleaner.